# Usage of #ifdef inside structure initialization

Tags: c

There are some values which are activated on certain #ifdef inside the structure. So, now on initializing and defining structure variable how will I use #ifdef inside structure initialization.

```
struct Godown
{
   int nPotatoes;
   int nTomatoes;
   #ifdef winters
      int nGarlics;
   #endif
};

Godown street1 = {10,20,
                       #ifdef winters
                          50
                       #endif
                  };
```

Comment: Your code is fine. What is the problem you are having? If you have error messages, then please add them to your question.

Comment: Im not sure if you are aware or not but keep in mind: `#ifdef`and other **Pre**processor directives are evaluated at compile time. Technically even before compile time (if you take it literally). So it is not a kind of a switch you can turn while your program runs but you need to compile your program twice to have both structures extended.

Answer (score 3):

That general approach will work but you'll need to absorb the comma into the `#ifdef`:

```
{
    10
    ,20
    #ifdef winters
        ,50
    #endif
};
```

The reasons for wanting to do this though are questionable.